# Being setup to fail?

Tags: management

I’ve been working for my current employer, a well funded startup, since day 1 for the last 6 years. I’ve always had great performance reviews, and have built a good team that recently shipped our first official consumer product.

Now, as part of a re-org I’m being asked by my boss to relinquish all my teams and responsibilities. Instead, I’ll be asked to lead a new never-before-existing team. This team currently has no headcount, and no headcount was requested in this budget cycle. The roles and responsibilities of this team are ill-defined, and it comes with no promotion. All the other “new” leads are being promoted to VP, beyond me. So I will be the only non-VP reporting to my
Boss.

I feel like I’m being moved “off critical path” to a staging role until they can collect enough data to fire me. Of course, a team with no headcount isn’t going to perform well, so it won’t take long

Is there any recourse here?

Comment: Do you have a substantial amount of equity in the company?

Comment: Enough to be valuable to me if we ever had a chance to exercise it (a few million). Not enough to have any authority (far less than 1%).

Comment: I guess you're already aware of their intention - get rid of you. Just look for a new job.

Comment: Does the thought of going to your boss with this same question make you anxious? If not, then it's completely worth doing. If so, then it would be worth your while to try to put your finger *exactly* on why; that'll be a good starting point on your relationship to your boss, and maybe his disposition towards you.

Comment: Is there a reason that your boss would want or need data to fire you?  Startups generally aren't in the business of firing founding employees with great reviews for no reason.  And depending on where you are, most startups are relatively free to let people go for whatever reason they want (or no reason).

Answer (score 9):

6 years is a long time and it's not uncommon that the company's needs change. Especially at senior management level. Even if you had done a great job in your capacity so far, it may just not be what the company needs now. This development might even be your boss trying to keep you at the company.
If you are worried, I'd talk to your boss. It's much easier and less damaging to let somebody go based on a mutual agreement (especially if they are senior, founding member etc). There you can perhaps secure your equity etc. if there is any issues.
Or you might find out they genuinely want you to succeed with your new team.

Comment: This was my first thought. The company is growing in a way that makes it hard for them to fit you somewhere, yet they're still hanging on (for now). I understand the negative default view here, but that might be a good sign, they're hoping to get you into a functioning role. It still may not work out, of course, and you should probably have a plan B, but until you know otherwise, I don't see a reason to not put all your effort into the new role, and do your best to find ways to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

**Have you talked to your boss about this?**

Before doing anything else, bring this up with your boss.  Explain that you feel your being taken off the critical path, and you cannot accomplish anything with a zero person team.  Do this today if possible.

**Next, begin job searching.**

The best reference for a new job is already having one.  If you think your job is about to end, beat them to the punch.  Six years at a startup is a long time.  When people ask why you are leaving just say "felt it was time to explore new opportunities" or something of that nature.